# is the integral of the derivative of f(x) always equal to f(x)??

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I know that integrals and derivatives are opposites so I thought the answer should be f(x), so I tried this out for the integral of the derivative of x, and I x+C. I do not understand.

Comment: $C$ is a constant. Think about going the other way - If you differentiate the result, what happens to $C$? It vanishes because it does not depend on $x$. There are infinitely many antiderivatives, up to a constant.

Comment: @JacobCheverie so the integral of the derivative of f(x)=f(x)+C???

Answer (score 1):

Differentiation is an operation that starts with one function and produces another. But that operation has the same output for different inputs. These functions are different

$$
f(x) = x^2,\quad g(x) = x^2 + 2, \quad h(x) = x^2 + \pi, \quad \ldots
$$

but they all have the same derivative, 
$$
k(x) = 2x.
$$
So it makes no sense to ask for **the** antiderivative of $k$, only for **an** antiderivative, perhaps $f$, or for **all** the antiderivatives: the functions $f(x) + C$ for $C$ any constant.

This explains what's going on when "integral" means "antiderivative". Those are "indefinite integrals". When you think of integrals as finding areas you are thinking about definite integrals.

The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus connects the two kinds of integrals. It makes precise mathematical sense of the vague "integrals and derivatives are opposites".